# C# - Cannot call a HttpConfiguration Extension Methods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, extension-methods, asp.net-web-api-routing

I cannot call an `HttpConfiguration` extension method:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;
...
      var config = new HttpConfiguration();
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();  // <-- error
```

> Error: 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a
>   definition for 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' and no extension method
>   'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried both with System.Web.Http version 4 and 5, and with ".NET Framework 4.5.2" and ".NET Framework 4".

What am I missing?

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpconfigurationextensions.maphttpattributeroutes(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration,System.Web.Http.Routing.IDirectRouteProvider))

Comment: Its working fine for me. var config = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Comment: @Pietro, make sure you have a reference to Assembly System.Web.Http.dll in your project where that code is being executed. Also try clearing bin folder and then rebuilding project

Comment: @Nkosi, I have it selected. Just a doubt about its version. I have: System.Web v. 4.0, System.Web.Http v. 4.0 and System.Web.Http.Owin v. 5.2.3. I can System.Web.Http v. 5.2.3 (to match Owin), but no System.Web > 4.0. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @Pietro, yes. use v5.2.3.0 of System.Web.Http

Comment: @Nkosi, I did it, and I also upgraded System.Web.Http.Formatting. It now works. Thank you.

Comment: @Pietro, added it as an answer.

Comment: @Pietro are you using Nuget or are you adding the references manually?

Comment: @Nkosi: I had to use both NuGet and Project > Add Reference..., where I could add more details. Do you know if it is possible to do the same thing through a configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a reference to `Assembly System.Web.Http.dll, v5.2.3.0` in your project where that code is being executed. `HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` was added to ASP.NET Web API 2.2 which requires the above mentioned version of the assembly.

Comment: Yes, but I also needed to upgrade `System.Net.Http.Formatting` to 5.2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem (strictly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878570/type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-missing-using-directive-or-assembly-r)) specifying in Project > Reference Manager:

```
Microsoft.Owin  2.0.2.0
Owin  1.0.0.0
System.Net.Http.Formatting  5.2.3.0
System.Web  4.0.0.0
System.Web.Http  5.2.3.0
System.Web.Http.Owin  5.2.3.0
```