# Type or namespace name could not be found (missing using directive or assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, using-directives, assembly-references

With this code:

```
using System.Web.Http;
class MyClass : IHttpActionResult
{ ... }
```

I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'IHttpActionResult' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

As shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult(v=vs.118).aspx), the IHttpActionResult interface is defined in `System.Web.Http`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Does your project have a reference to System.Web.Http.dll?

Comment: You need to add the [Web API NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/)

Comment: @Igor: I already added it.

Comment: Did you restore your packages? If you expand references in visual studio you should see all referenced libraries listed without indicators that they are missing.

Comment: What about the selected framework for the project (in project properties). Do you have `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` selected?

Comment: I have `.Net Framework 4.5.2` selected. In the list, I have `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile`, but not `.Net Framework 4.5.2 Client Profile`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Yes, it is selected. But I have a doubt about the version. I have 4.0.0 (selected) and 5.2.3, with a .Net Framework version 4.5.2. Should I install a version matching with the .Net Framework one?

Comment: @Pietro IIRC you're OK with a lower .NET version in the library than your project version. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem (strictly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878296/c-sharp-cannot-call-a-httpconfiguration-extension-methods)) specifying in Project > Reference Manager:

```
Microsoft.Owin  2.0.2.0
Owin  1.0.0.0
System.Net.Http.Formatting  5.2.3.0
System.Web  4.0.0.0
System.Web.Http  5.2.3.0
System.Web.Http.Owin  5.2.3.0
```